# abstract class and interface what will be change

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class

we have an abstract class `Parent`, and two other classes : `class ChildOne` and `Childtwo`, both inherit from `Parent`.

Question: if we declare `Parent` as an interface, what will happen or change at `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` when both implements this interface?

Comment: What do you mean by *decline `Parent` as an interface*? Also, `Parent` can only be abstract class or interface, not both.

Comment: decline Parent as an interface. i guess you meant define. well depends on how you want to design. one simple advantage you get using interface is option of implementing from multiple hierarchy trees.

Comment: If you change `Parent` from an abstract class to an interface, it *may* take slightly longer to call the methods polymorphically, since a class can implement multiple interfaces meaning the data structures behind them have to be a little more complex.  However, this is just speculation and I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Syntax, those classes will need to `implements Parent` instead of `extends Parent`
2. In Java 7 or before, interfaces cannot contain method implementations so you will need to rewrite them in `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`. (Since Java8, you can write default methods implementations in interfaces).
3. Since an interface cannot hold atrributes, you will also need to duplicate them in `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo`.

Comment: Java 8 also supports static methods in interfaces now.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I do not understand the difference with what I wrote.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle There's a big difference between a `default` method and a `static` method.  `Default` methods are instance methods, but they don't have to be implemented in an implementing class since the default is provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you turn an abstract class into an interface, you will need to

- implement the interface instead of extending the class
- not call super() constructor.
- not call any super method.
- make any method overriding/implementing methods in the interface public.  Methods in an abstract class don't have to be public.

Comment: Also make sure you refactor out any implemented methods in the abstract parent into a child class.

Comment: @Qix I assume the interface compiles but the child class need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean define, when u say decline in "if we decline Parent as an interface," changes shall be as follows. 
1. You shall loose functionality written in parent class.
2. Whatever abstract functions  you shall define in interface ( replaceing Parent ), you shall have to write different independent implementations for Children.

Answer (score 0):

When you have `Parent` as abstract class, the `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` will inherit the non-abstract methods defined in `Parent`. Which means, `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` will attain some functionality from `Parent` by default. This is particularly useful, when `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` have some common functionality, which can be placed in the `Parent`.

When you make the `Parent` as interface, `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` will need to implement all the methods in the `Parent`.

Answer (score 0):

> what will happen or change at `ChildOne` and `ChildTwo` when both
>   implements this interface

Nothing will happen to those - they'll just be able to extend some different class (because in Java a class can only extend one class, but can implement many interfaces). So it's better to declare Parent as interface instead of abstract class, if possible.

It is of course impossible to change `Parent` from abstract class to interface if you have some fields, constructors or non-abstract methods defined in Parent. Remember, interface can only hold abstract method declarations - no fields, methods implementations or constructor declarations (unless we're speaking of static fields/methods, but these are out of the question when we talk about inheritance).